# Looking to pin content above a segmented controller below parallax header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, user-experience

I realize this is a general question, but any direction would be helpful.

So I am using this module https://github.com/maxep/MXSegmentedPager  to try and recreate Twitter's profile page. One thing I am unsure how to do is get content above the HMSegmentedControl but is still pinned to it so it scrolls out of the way. When i add subviews to the parallax header view (in the xib file) they are totally static and dont move with the HMSegmentedControl menu.

Any ideas how I would tweak it? I dove into the MXSegmentedPager.m file but to no avail.

I suppose what I'm looking for is can i expand and put content inside a UIPageControl or in this case HMSegmentedControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was pointed in the right direction by the author of the module I was using, MXSegmentedPager. His MXParallax header already has space for content above the HMSegmentedControl and can be used for more than just one image.

Turns out any subviews you want to pin need their constraints to be referenced to the background imageView, not the superview. Only the background imageView itself its set to the superview of the nib.

Also, when putting several things in a uiview thats sitting on top of the background imageView, make sure it is referencing the background imageView but not on all 4 sides, otherwise it appears static. Typically you will want to set it to bottom left and right, and set a fixed height equal to height of the header you want to view when its at its resting visible point.

So, in hindsight fairly simple, but I overlooked it.